# Users not being tracked in Google Analytics 4 using Google Tag Manager Server

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am trying to send event data to Google Analytics 4 through a Google Tag Manager Server container. This setup will later be used to track an app for which we will not be using the Google SDK. However whatever I try, I can't seem to record users within GA4, even though the events are recorded.

Currently, I send an HTTP POST request from Postman to our Google Tag Manager Server container, which is captured by a custom Client and is processed by the official GA4 tag. Within the GA4 tag, I map the original event data to the event data needed by GA4. The request that is sent is shown below:

[image]Also, GTM shows a 204 response code.

[image]

When the GA4 tag sends the request to GA4, I do see the event coming in, but no user is recorded:

[image: The real-time GA4 report showing events but no user.]

Which parameters am I missing that are required?

(Yes, I know that there are dedicated App streams within GA4, but you have to connect your account to Firebase, which is exactly what we do not want for our setup. Therefore, I set up a web stream.)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.